# Get content page using visitor IP

Tags: php

How I can get content of web page using visitor IP? I can't do it by AJAX because the page is using CROSS-DOMAIN policy.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I have to get content of web page (HTML code) - http://vshare.io/d/f3c85be. You can see - on this web page is Download URL. This URL is generated for user's IP - every user has another download link. I need to get this link for every visitor. I can't get this URL using AJAX because this page is using CROSS-DOMAIN POLICY. I can't get this content using CURL because this URL will generated for IP of my server (not visitor IP) and exacly it won't work.

Comment: What do you mean `getting content of a web page using IP`? What webpage? Visitor visiting what? Show us some code.

Comment: I edited my first question.

Answer (score -1):

How I can get content of web page using visitor IP?

You don't need an IP to get a webpage.

You need the url to the page and you can use $`homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');`
echo `$homepage;`

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, maybe you're referring to the IP address being the url then you can do this

```
file_get_contents('http://192.168.1.1/content.html');`
echo `$homepage;`
```

You can use the function below to get their ip address. Don't use the short built in php function to get that, it won't always guarantee an IP address.

```
function getUserIP()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}


$user_ip = getUserIP();

echo $user_ip; // Output IP address [Ex: 177.87.193.134]
```

Comment: then all you need is $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; to get the users url. This will not give your servers url but the users url for instance http://vshare.io/d/f3c85be

Comment: hmm... I don't understand you or you doesn't understand me. My web page address is (for example): my-page.com and I want to get download link from http://vshare.io/d/f3c85be for EVERY VISITOR of my page (my-page.com) so everything what I have is visitor IP. And how I can generate this Download URL based on visitor IP?

Comment: do you have their url information stored anywhere in the db? this information would go well kept in the db.

Comment: No, I didn't because this Download URL is unique. Every visit this site: http://vshare.io/d/f3c85be causes generate a new Download URL so I can't stored this URLs in database. I need to get this download URL in present.